# Noun for adjective "reservable"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

In English, is it correct to use the term 'reservability' for the ability to reserve a room?

Or is the term 'bookability' preferable?
Or anything else?

Context: I'm translating a room reservation software system, where you can set whether a room in a building is bookable in a selection field named 'bookability' with choices yes and no (and null/void).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about **availability**?

I think that would be the correct term in this case.

Comment: I'm gonna call it 'Availability for booking'

Comment: @Quandry - there is a difference though: "Available" means nobody else has booked it, but "reservable" would mean is it possible to book in advance. So a train might have seats available but they aren't reservable - ie. you can't ensure one is kept for you

Answer (score 1):

It's common for hotels to show a neon sign with the text "No vacancy" to express that no room is available.  So naturally, I would assume a good way to describe the "reservability" would be to call it vacant.

Answer (score 0):

my vote is masarah's answer. Is the room available or not is what you are asking.

You can reserve a room that is available.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer...

Answer (score 0):

maintainable brings a different tone to it, but means the same.  Both words have the sense of preservation, or perhaps, upkeep.